# Multicast UDP packets using Tokio futures

Tags: sockets, rust, udp, rust-tokio

I'm playing around with Tokio and Rust and as an example, I am trying to write a simple UDP proxy that will just accept UDP packets on one socket and send it out to multiple other destinations. However, I stumble over the situation that I need to send the received packet to multiple addresses and am not sure how to do that in a idiomatic way.

Code I have this far:

```
extern crate bytes;
extern crate futures;

use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio::codec::BytesCodec;
use tokio::net::{UdpFramed, UdpSocket};
use tokio::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let listen_address = "127.0.0.1:4711".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
    let forwarder = {
        let socket = UdpSocket::bind(&listen_address).unwrap();
        let peers = vec![
            "192.168.1.136:4711".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap(),
            "192.168.1.136:4712".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap(),
        ];
        UdpFramed::new(UdpSocket::bind(&listen_address).unwrap(), BytesCodec::new()).for_each(
            move |(bytes, _from)| {
                // These are the problematic lines
                for peer in peers.iter() {
                    socket.send_dgram(&bytes, &peer);
                }
                Ok(())
            },
        )
    };

    tokio::run({
        forwarder
            .map_err(|err| println!("Error: {}", err))
            .map(|_| ())
    });
}
```

The problematic lines are trying to send the received packet to multiple other addresses using a newly bound socket.

The existing examples all forward packets to single destinations, or internally use mpsc channels to communicate between internal tasks. I do not think that this is necessary and that it should be possible to do without having to spawn more than one task per listening socket.

**Update:** Thanks to @Ömer-erden I got this code that works.

```
extern crate bytes;
extern crate futures;

use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio::codec::BytesCodec;
use tokio::net::{UdpFramed, UdpSocket};
use tokio::prelude::*;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let listen_address = "0.0.0.0:4711".parse::<SocketAddr>()?;
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(&listen_address)?;
    let peers: Vec<SocketAddr> = vec!["192.168.1.136:8080".parse()?, "192.168.1.136:8081".parse()?];
    let (mut writer, reader) = UdpFramed::new(socket, BytesCodec::new()).split();
    let forwarder = reader.for_each(move |(bytes, _from)| {
        for peer in peers.iter() {
            writer.start_send((bytes.clone().into(), peer.clone()))?;
        }
        writer.poll_complete()?;
        Ok(())
    });

    tokio::run({
        forwarder
            .map_err(|err| println!("Error: {}", err))
            .map(|_| ())
    });
    Ok(())
}
```

Note that:

- It is not necessary to call `poll_completion` for each `start_send`: it just need to be called after all `start_send` has been dispatched.
- For some reason, the content of the `peer` is gutted between calls (but there is no compiler error), generating an Error 22 (which is usually because a bad address is given to `sendto(2)`).

  Looking in a debugger, it is quite clear that the second time, the peer address is pointing to invalid memory. I opted to clone the `peer` instead.
- I removed the calls to `unwrap()` and propagate the `Result` upwards instead.

Comment: Why not multicast on the network level instead?

Comment: @PeterHall But multicast is a completely different story, especially as listeners need to "register" themselves to listen to particular multicast (at least to do it correctly).

Comment: @PeterHall The most important reason is that I am wondering how to execute a set of futures dynamically, but IP multicast has restrictions on both the sender and the receiver in that they have to be aware of multicast groups (edit: that is, register to receive messages sent to the group).

Comment: @MatsKindahl IMVHO you should have 2 sockets, one listener on local IF, second to transmit on exposed IF, otherwise packets sent would have source address of loopback.

Comment: @Manveru In this example, yes, but if the address of the sender is important, then registering using the wildcard address will give the actual address used for the socket, so it is not *necessary* to have two sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a logical mistake: you are trying to bind the same address twice, as sender and receiver respectively. Instead, you can use a **stream and sink**. `UdpFramed` has the functionality to provide that, please see [`Sink`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html):

> A `Sink` is a value into which other values can be sent, asynchronously.

```rust
let listen_address = "127.0.0.1:4711".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
let forwarder = {
    let (mut socket_sink, socket_stream) =
        UdpFramed::new(UdpSocket::bind(&listen_address).unwrap(), BytesCodec::new()).split();
    let peers = vec![
        "192.168.1.136:4711".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap(),
        "192.168.1.136:4712".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap(),
    ];

    socket_stream.for_each(move |(bytes, _from)| {
        for peer in peers.iter() {
            socket_sink.start_send((bytes.clone().into(), *peer));
            socket_sink.poll_complete();
        }
        Ok(())
    })
};

tokio::run({
    forwarder
        .map_err(|err| println!("Error: {}", err))
        .map(|_| ())
});
```

Comment: It has hardly anything to do with using two sockets (the same code could use two different sockets), but it avoids having to create two sockets, which was also something I was wondering about. I was looking for the `start_send` and `poll_complete` functions. Many thanks.You might want to rewrite the answer for others and highlight this.

Comment: @MatsKindahl actually `start_send` and `poll_complete` functions are behavior of the `Sink` structure, i will add link to provide more detail about Sink.